# Capturing only one <div> of website client side

Tags: html, css, parsing, geektool

I'm trying to get some stats from my Halo character onto my desktop. Right now I have a geektool script that turns [a service record page](http://halo.xbox.com/en-us/Career/ServiceRecord?gamertag=Cosssta) into a .png, and then puts that on my desktop. However, I would like it just to display the ***div class="summary-details"***

What would be the best way to do this? I was thinking of writing some kind of python script that would parse the page, copy the necessary style and content sections, then make a new html document every 15 minutes or so. However, I did some research and learned that parsing with regular expressions is not advised. What should I use to parse the page? I'd prefer using something for python. Thanks.

Comment: What is your intended end-use for this? To embed in another website?

Comment: I just wanted to put it on my desktop. I ended up figuring out how to do it, but I kind of cheated. I used imagemagick to crop the png I used to the size and area of the specific thing I wanted, and then put that on my desktop with geektool. It'll all get messed up if the website changes their layout, but I was having a hard time sorting through everything with the parser. If it breaks at least I know how to fix it.

Comment: If they change something with the website there's a good chance they'll have changed the markup too, that would probably break your parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is well suited for parsing HTML. However it's not going to be easy to produce an image of this `div` as it appears on the website.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was worried this would be difficult; I'll give beautiful soup a go.